# Append another value at end of specific key-value in an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an Array of object, something like this:

```
const sample = [
{
    key:"key1",
    title: "title1", 
    value: "value1"
},
{
    key:"key2",
    title: "title2", 
    value: "value2"
},
{
    key:"key3",
    title: "title3", 
    value: "value3"
}
```

]

Now I want to append some value at the end of each object 'title' key like this:

```
const sample = [
{
    key:"key1",
    title: "title1 + 1", 
    value: "value1"
},
{
    key:"key2",
    title: "title2 + 2", 
    value: "value2"
},
{
    key:"key3",
    title: "title3 + 3", 
    value: "value3"
}
```

]

I know how to modify, add the key but not sure about how to append the data in such way.
please suggest some solution for the mentioned problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the object by taking the index for the value.

```js
const
    sample = [{ key:"key1", title: "title1",  value: "value1" }, { key:"key2", title: "title2",  value: "value2" }, { key:"key3", title: "title3",  value: "value3" }],
    result = sample.map((o, i) => ({ ...o, title: o.title + (i + 1) }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks @Nina for answer just want to understand, so we are creating new key 'title' and appending the data to existing one. in that way we are updating the objects 
is it right?

Comment: right, but you get new objects without mutating existing data.

Comment: ok got it. we will get new array 'result' with updated object as we are using map. 
Any Idea on how to to update the existing array with mutated values?? I mean if its possible.

Comment: take `sample.forEach((o, i) => o.title += i + 1);`. this updates all objects.

Comment: understood. this one will update all objects. Thanks again.

Comment: one question though here we are just updating the value based on ieach teration. 
So if i want to add some specific value to specific object let's say on second object 
{
    "key": "key2",
    "title": "title2 + 23423",
    "value": "value2"
  }
and third object only 
{
    "key": "key3",
    "title": "title3 + will_i_am",
    "value": "value3"
  }
then i guess we need to put a check for each one right?

Comment: if you like to mutate the data, you could take an index instead looping all items.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const sample = [
{
    key:"key1",
    title: "title1", 
    value: "value1"
},
{
    key:"key2",
    title: "title2", 
    value: "value2"
},
{
    key:"key3",
    title: "title3", 
    value: "value3"
}]

let result = sample.map((x, i) => {
  x.title = x.title + ' + ' + (i + 1);
  return x;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :) Transform in the map the value, as you want! :)

```js
const sample = [
    {
        key:"key1",
        title: "title1 + 1",
        value: "value1"
    },
    {
        key:"key2",
        title: "title2 + 2",
        value: "value2"
    },
    {
        key:"key3",
        title: "title3 + 3",
        value: "value3"
    }
];
const other = sample.map(val => ({...val, title: val.title + 'anything'}));
console.log(other);
```